# how enable relateve import to target file, not to index?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are 3 files

1.ts

```
export const testA = 1;
```

index.ts

```
export * from './1'
```

2.ts

```
import * from '.'
```

When the `2.ts` file is saved, vscode add imports to `index.ts`

I need `import * from '.'` to transform to `import * from './2'`

Here is my `settings.js`

```
{
    "git.ignoreWindowsGit27Warning": true,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "angular.experimental-ivy": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
    "typescript.preferences.includePackageJsonAutoImports": "on",
    "eslint.enable": true,
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "javascript.suggest.autoImports": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.addMissingImports": true,
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
        "source.organizeImports": true
    },
    "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"
}
```

[image: example gif]

Comment: I don't know anything about typescript, but why would you **ever** use digit-only code file names?

Comment: @JansthcirlU cos it examle